# Ajax Popup calender Postback automatically issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax

In the below code, after selecting the date, date is reset to default value.

Because IN postback I set the current date,How to overcome this issue,

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="ExpiryDateTxt" CssClass="textbox" AutoPostBack="true"    ReadOnly="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  

       <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender   
               ID="startCalendarExtender"   Format="MM/dd/yyyy"
                TargetControlID="ExpiryDateTxt"   
                runat="server" /> 

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          if (!IsPostBack)
          {
                ExpiryDateTxt.Text =DateTime.Now.AddDays(1.0).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
           }
     }
```

Comment: can't you instantiate an object of the current date picker and deal with it instead of using the main one??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that ReadOnly="true" cause this issue.

You can use javascript to make the textbox is readonly

```
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
    <asp:TextBox ID="ExpiryDateTxt" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="textbox read-only" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  

    <cc1:CalendarExtender
        ID="startCalendarExtender" Format="MM/dd/yyyy"
        TargetControlID="ExpiryDateTxt"   
        runat="server" /> 

     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
             $('.read-only').attr("readonly", "readonly");
        });
     </script>
```

Comment: Ya Updated one also not updating properly

Comment: my approach only affects only on client, it does not affect the ViewState of control, so on server side, it's ReadOnly still false.